# Lua error handling

Tags: error-handling, lua

I'm new to lua.

I've tried to use 
http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/examples.html
and it throws an error on inaccessible directories.

This appears to be caused by **luaL_error** https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem/blob/master/src/lfs.c#L563

How can I catch this error?
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_error_handling.htm
suggests `pcall`, however that doesn't stop the script from dying:

```
pcall(lfs.dir('/etc/passwd')) #this fails to handle the not a directory error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pcall(lfs.dir('/etc/passwd'))` fails because the error is triggered outside of `pcall` (when the parameter for pcall is calculated). You need to use

```
local ok, res = pcall(lfs.dir, '/etc/passwd')
```

Note that the parameters passed to `lfs.dir` are given to `pcall`, not to `lfs.dir`.